# I cant reach for the last element in my layout via scrollView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview

I am working on an android app, and now I am putting a simple form in the dialog box this form I wanna used for address info, and it has multi-element.

the layout for the dialog has scrollView.

the scrollView is existing and I can scroll up and down but I can't scroll down to reach for the last item in my layout.

### My layout:

```html
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:padding="24dp">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/address"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/post_code"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>
                <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="1"
                android:background="@drawable/stork_wo">
                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:inputType="textPostalAddress"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:hint="@string/post_code"
                    android:id="@+id/etPostCode"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    android:layout_weight="0.9"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:layout_margin="1dp"
                    android:background="@color/white"/>

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:drawableEnd="@drawable/search"
                    android:drawableRight="@drawable/search"
                    android:drawablePadding="8dp"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:id="@+id/btnSearch"
                    android:drawableTint="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:layout_weight="0.1"/>

                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/select_an_address"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimary" />

                <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:entries="@array/array_empty"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />
                <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/flat_number"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>
                <EditText
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:ems="10"
                android:background="@drawable/stork_wo"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:id="@+id/etFlatNumber"
                android:hint="@string/flat_num_example"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimary" />

                <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/address2"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>
                <EditText
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:ems="10"
                android:background="@drawable/stork_wo"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:id="@+id/etAddress2"
                android:hint="@string/address2_example"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimary" />

                <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/town"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>
                <EditText
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:ems="10"
                android:background="@drawable/stork_wo"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:id="@+id/etTown"
                android:hint="@string/town_example"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimary" />

                <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/city"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>
                <EditText
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:ems="10"
                android:background="@drawable/stork_wo"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:id="@+id/etCity"
                android:hint="@string/town_example"
                android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnNext"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/button"
            android:text="@string/save"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingTop="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/button"
            android:text="@string/cancel"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingTop="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

I don't know what I missed!

any Help please?

and thanks

Comment: Can you try for NestedScrollView ?

Comment: yes! I use it and now it is working perfectly! Thank u for advice <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace **ScrollView** with **NestedScrollView**, as you used Spinner inside the ScrollView which has own scroll view.

Here is changed Xml Code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:background="@color/white"
android:padding="24dp">
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/address"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/post_code"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="1"
            android:background="@drawable/stork_wo">
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:inputType="textPostalAddress"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/post_code"
                android:id="@+id/etPostCode"
                android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:layout_weight="0.9"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:layout_margin="1dp"
                android:background="@color/white"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:drawableEnd="@drawable/search"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/search"
                android:drawablePadding="8dp"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:id="@+id/btnSearch"
                android:drawableTint="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:layout_weight="0.1"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/select_an_address"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimary" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:entries="@array/array_empty"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/flat_number"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:ems="10"
            android:background="@drawable/stork_wo"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:id="@+id/etFlatNumber"
            android:hint="@string/flat_num_example"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimary" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/address2"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:ems="10"
            android:background="@drawable/stork_wo"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:id="@+id/etAddress2"
            android:hint="@string/address2_example"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimary" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/town"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:ems="10"
            android:background="@drawable/stork_wo"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:id="@+id/etTown"
            android:hint="@string/town_example"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimary" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/city"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:ems="10"
            android:background="@drawable/stork_wo"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:id="@+id/etCity"
            android:hint="@string/town_example"
            android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnNext"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/button"
            android:text="@string/save"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingTop="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/button"
            android:text="@string/cancel"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingTop="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Hope, it works for you!!!

Answer (score 1):

It will works in ScrollView Just move android:layout_marginTop="40dp" from LinearLayout to TextView.

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:background="@color/white"
android:padding="24dp">
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/address"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/post_code"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>
            <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="1"
            android:background="@drawable/stork_wo">
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:inputType="textPostalAddress"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/post_code"
                android:id="@+id/etPostCode"
                android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:layout_weight="0.9"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:layout_margin="1dp"
                android:background="@color/white"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:drawableEnd="@drawable/search"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/search"
                android:drawablePadding="8dp"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:id="@+id/btnSearch"
                android:drawableTint="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:layout_weight="0.1"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/select_an_address"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimary" />

            <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:entries="@array/array_empty"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />
            <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/flat_number"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>
            <EditText
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:ems="10"
            android:background="@drawable/stork_wo"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:id="@+id/etFlatNumber"
            android:hint="@string/flat_num_example"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimary" />

            <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/address2"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>
            <EditText
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:ems="10"
            android:background="@drawable/stork_wo"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:id="@+id/etAddress2"
            android:hint="@string/address2_example"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimary" />

            <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/town"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>
            <EditText
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:ems="10"
            android:background="@drawable/stork_wo"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:id="@+id/etTown"
            android:hint="@string/town_example"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimary" />

            <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/city"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>
            <EditText
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:ems="10"
            android:background="@drawable/stork_wo"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:id="@+id/etCity"
            android:hint="@string/town_example"
            android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnNext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/button"
        android:text="@string/save"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/button"
        android:text="@string/cancel"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp" />

</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

as @Nice umang Adviced me to use NestedScrollView I do.

and now it's work successfully..

### this is my new layout:

```html
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:padding="24dp">
    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/nestedScrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:overScrollMode="never">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true">

     .....
     
    </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```